# haskell type signature question

Tags: haskell, type-signature

Can someone explain me, why do these functions 
have **different number of arguments and behavior**, but
the **same type signature**, yet they are both correct?

```
comp1 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
comp1 f g = g.f

comp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
comp2 f g x = g (f x)
```

also, why does comp2 has

```
comp2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

instead of something like

```
comp2 :: a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion ?

Comment: In which way do the two functions have different behavior? Looks the same to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
comp2 f g x = g (f x)
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
comp2 = \f -> \g -> \x -> g (f x)
```

Similarly

```
comp1 f g = g.f
```

is sugar for

```
comp1 = \f -> \g -> g.f
```

The definition of `.` is:

```
f1 . f2 = \x -> f1 (f2 x) -- Names of arguments have been changed to avoid confusion
```

So if we insert the definition into the desugared form of `comp1`, we get:

```
comp1 = \f -> \g -> \x -> g (f x)
```

This is exactly the same as the desugared form of `comp2`, so clearly the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

`comp1 f g = g.f` is written in [**point-free**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style (not referring to points, but to *values*). When you call `comp1`, there is implicitly a third parameter being passed to `g.f`, which is the composition of the two functions `g` and `f`: `(g.f) x` equals `g (f x)`, i.e. `g` is passed the result of `f x`. No parameter `x` exists in `comp1` because it's implicitly passed to the function. (You could think of `comp1` as a *partially applied* or *curried* function if it makes you feel better.)

`comp2`'s type asks for two functions, one from `(a->b)` and another `(b->c)`, as well as a parameter of type `a`. There is no need to put an `a ->` in its signature.

The two functions are really equivalent; one simply uses some Haskell tricks to be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). A multi-argument function in ML and Haskell, is just syntactic sugar for a one-argument function that returns a function; the function that it returns takes the remaining arguments.